# Why is torsional shear for a circular cross-section maximum at the biggest radius

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, stress-strain

Equation: Tao = (T*C)/J

i know the equation but it just seems counter-intuitive that the maximum shear stress is at the biggest radius for 3 reasons that I have(thought of).

1- imagine/assume that the applied force propagates (like water waves) in an equidistant manner, or in a circular manner for a cross-sectional view which is in 2D. As the force propagates further away from the center (assuming the torsion is applied at the center), the stress should decrease because the surface area increases as the radius increases (stress is N/M^2)

2- the axle-wheel friction analogy: it is a well known fact that as the axle diameter decreases the axle-wheel friction decreases because the friction's leverage is smaller at smaller axle diameters (thus static & dynamic friction are lesser in magnitude for smaller axle diameters). Thinking of it Intuitively, a smaller axle will try to push the wheel closer to its center which is harder. Similarly, the reaction friction force of the wheel will be less effective on a smaller diameter axle since it is pushing the axle from its edges which are close to the center as well. I don't know whether I can say there is friction/connection between the particles of a solid circular shaft in the same way but I think that the concept of leverage applies here just as it applies for the axle-wheel analogy since torsion is essential bending moment(s). If so, then in a circular cross-section, it should be easier for smaller diameters to shear relative to each other (rather than move with each other; lesser friction/connection force at smaller diameters due to reduced leverage). For the same reasons, larger diameters should feel the opposite. Consequently, this should cause earlier yielding at smaller diameters than at larger diameters for the same applied force(s). (Stress increases as strain increases. So again stress should be greater at smaller diameters)
*** (the main contradiction of this part to the literature is that: if this was true, a material at smaller diameters will need SLIGHTLY lesser stress to strain for all points on the curve(since it is easier to strain at smaller leverage) than needed at the larger diameters. This would contradict (only a little bit) the notion that each material has a constant, defined stress-strain curve/behavior.) )

3- based on (2-): as smaller diameters are more prone to elastically deform than larger diameters. There should be some force that goes into motion-deformation at smaller diameters more than at larger diameters (some force is translated into motion-deformation (relieved) instead of stress, thus the force(s) propagating towards later, bigger radii is/are less than the initial force(s), which should further decrease the shear stress at larger diameters than at smaller diameters)

I am not sure whether these reasons are valid/true that's why I was skeptical about mentioning them at first. So can these reasons be valid ?? If so, then are there any other missing factors that make stress maximum at the biggest radii  regardless of the 3 factors I mentioned ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mr.Bean I think you should see it in terms of deformation instead of force (since stress depends on the deformation of the material). You may imagine two hollow shafts (tubes) that have different diameters (one smaller than the other), and you deform both of them applying a torsional force, so both of them are deformed by 90 degrees, and think about which of them has deformed the most [link](https://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/Structures.d/IAST.Lect07.d/IAST.Lect07.pdf)

Comment: @ user190081, " so both of them are deformed by 90 degrees, and think about which one of them has deformed the most" you just said that they both are deformed by 90 degrees so how can one deform more than the other ??

Comment: @user190081, you don't answer my questions directly. Also what is wrong with seeing it in terms of force (if stress is dependent on deformation, force is the cause of deformation). Are you sure you understood my reasoning and what I am trying to say ?? I know my writing style is quite clumsy so I don't really blame you for not understanding.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be overcomplicating this. The equation for torsional stress a distance $r$ from the center of circular solid or thick-walled shafts (thickness > 0.1r) is given by
$$τ=\frac{Tr}{J}$$ where $J$ is the polar moment of inertia for a circular solid of radius $a$ given by, 
$$J=\frac {πa^4}{2}$$
So for a given polar moment of inertia, the torsional stress is proportional to the distance $r$ from the center, thereby being maximum at maximum $r$. So the outer portion of the shaft experiences maximum torsional shear stress. One reason why drive shafts are hollow. Saves on material.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but I know this already. However knowing it is one thing, relating it to intuition is something else. As it stands, there is a contradiction for me between what is generally accepted and what I intuitively believe in (my reasoning)

Comment: @Mr.Bean. OK understood. Just wanted to make sure about what you knew. I will look again at your 3 reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot mr. Bob. Appreciate your help and enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

I think deformation is the answer.As pointed out by user190081, the angular deformation may be same but if we consider two circular strips one near the centre and one far from it, the points on the outer strips will be displaced more than the points on the inner strip for the same angular deformation.This might be a reason.

Comment: That is a simplistic view. You are assuming that there is no relative deformation between the smaller and bigger diameters of a solid circular cross section under torsion. this is probably a wrong assumption. Appreciate your help though, thanks.

Comment: I am arguing that there should be relative deformation in favor of smaller diameters (more deformation at smaller diameters) because of the weaker leverage they have to transmit the stress to larger diameters (if we assume that the torque is applied from the center). THAT'S BRIEFLY WHAT POINT 2 IS ALL ABOUT !!!

Comment: But the problem is stress is not the action, it is the reaction(actually resistence).Deformation or  elongation is the action.When you twist the member, the points near the centre deform less and far away from the centre deform more.Then they divide the load in such a way that the points near the centre resist smaller part and those farther resist larger part of the load.

Comment: Deformation/strain is not the cause for stress. Strain does increase stress however as it happens. Regardless, what is your proof or reasoning that the points closer to the center deform less than the farthest points ?? And how do they divide the force between them ?? You must have some reasoning if you are talking like that, so please share it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok.What is the cause of stress?

Comment: Force is the cause for both stress and strain

Comment: At the instant where a point is straining or deforming, the force is not translated into stress but into acceleration/deformation by F=ma.  That's what I believe

Comment: From what I learnt, in a member between the bonding atoms there will be an attractive and a repulsive force.Normally the distance between the two atoms is such that the two forces nullify each other.When you apply a tensile load on the member, the force will try to icrease the distance between the atoms.Then the attractive force increases with increase in distance.This continues till a point and then decreases and filnally the material fails.So the force causes increase in distance which in turn causes increase in attractive force(this is the stress).

Comment: Yes I believe the same. But this doesn't contradict my earlier comments I think. what's the point that you are trying to make??

Comment: Iam so sorry.Now I understood your comment.So there is relative deformation betwee the layers.The moment is applied at the centre and the deformation progresses from the centre.If it is so, I think finite element analysis may give you the right answer(I dont have much knowledege about it).But you can try posting this question in engineering stack exchange.I think there were a few people experienced in FEA and machine design.

Comment: But if you are an undergrad student and trying to compare the real life situation with your conventional "Strength of materials" equations(I did it during my college),understand that there are a lot of simplifications assumed in those equations.In case of twisting moments acting on a shaft at the centre of the cross section, there will not be any relative deformation between the circular elements on the cross section.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Thank you for your help, comments and also for the +1 

Comment: Yes I am an undergraduate. Sadly the equations we take are confusing me and causing me to think such thoughts involuntarily. I just want to know the truth and the more assumptions and simplifications there are the more inaccurate(rubbish) are the equations from the truth. AS AN UNDERGRAD MY INTUITION IS BEING F**KED UP

Answer (score 0):

I too felt fidgety when reading this but I think it's entirely due to a lack of a visceral understanding of the moment of inertia. So to make myself more clear I would like to present my attaché of facts followed by the intuition. Please bear with me as I do not know to present with equations and expressions.

We already know how the moment of inertia is the measure of an object's resistance to move, and it's analog for rotating, the mass MI and the one for bending, Area MI(about an axis for the case of area moment of inertia and about a point for polar moment of inertia or 2nd moment of area). And since the goal is to find how much of the area is how far from the axis of rotation because farther away the area is, the harder it is to twist. Thus we take the square of the distance because if we would have taken the only the distance multiplied by the differential area and summed over the entire region then for equidistant differential area, but on the different side of the axis, the product of distance and the differential areas would cancel out. And hence for all symmetric objects the value will amount to zero.

I hope these videos will help to re-enforce your rationale and develop that gut feeling.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z19iwclwY14&t=230s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bls5KnQOWkY&t=139s

Now for the intuition part.

Imagine the cross-section of a circular shaft divided into circular strips with dr thickness and at i*dr distance from the centre with i going from 0 to n. If the torque is applied to the centre of the shaft and as you mention that the force propagates radially, then the circular strip nearer to the shaft will rotate more readily and the strip adjacent to it will provide more resistance  to rotation because of having a higher area MI compared to the inner strip. We can imagine this resistance as a form of pseudo-force which linearly increases for further out we go radially.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the intuition behind it, you need to know what is going on exactly. It's all about geometry, and it's not a static equilibrium requirement.

For beams with circular cross-sections (for small displacements):

- The angular deformation per unit length is a constant.
- Cross-sections remain as planes.

Then, **the geometry dictates that** the displacement of a point in the cross-section is linearly proportional to the distance between the point and the origin (distance r). To show this, draw a disc on paper, select a point on the disc, and calculate its x and y displacements as if the disc was rotated by $\alpha$ degrees (don't forget to use the small angle approximation).

Then, **Hooke's law dictates that** stress needs to have the same relationship with the distance r as displacement does. Therefore, stress must be linearly proportional to the distance r.

*Note: I didn't understand your three arguments. I think you can write them more clearly. However, this should answer your questions. The geometry constraint is pretty clear.*